# Comprobar caracter a caracter en tiempo real un String mediante expresion regular

Tags: regex, javafx

Quisiera que mientras escribo caracteres se fuera comprobando si el nuevo String cumple con lo que en la expresion regular hay definido.

Cabe decir que el Strign lo voy introduciendo en un TextField

esta es la expresion regular-->"[0-9]{8}[A-Z]"

este el codigo del evento:

```
  public RestrictiveField(){

   textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

         //patron.get() es el metodo que carga el patron 
        Pattern p= Pattern.compile(patron.get());
          Matcher m= p.matcher(newValue);
          if(!m.lookingAt()){

                setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red; -fx-font-size: 16;");
                   } 
            if(newValue.equals("")|| m.lookingAt()){

                setStyle("fx-control-inner-background: transparent;");

            }
          }  
      });

}
```

La salida de esto, es justo la contraria a la que busco con el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Para los resultados parciales, prueba con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?:\d{8}[A-Z]|\d{1,8})$
```

Tienes una demo **[aquí](https://regex101.com/r/ceDpZ3/2/)**.

Después, una vez se submita el formulario, valida con la expresión regular original

`^[0-9]{8}[A-Z]$`

Answer (score 0):

T agradezco la respuesta pero (quizás me explique mal ) pero no responde a mi problema.

el problema no es la expresion regular sino los métodos a emplear.
recientemente lo solucione:

```
 public RestrictiveField(){
```

textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {

```
     //patron.get() es el metodo que carga el patron 
    Pattern p= Pattern.compile(patron.get());
      Matcher m= p.matcher(newValue);
      m.matches();
      if(!m.hitEnd()()){

            setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: red; -fx-font-size: 16;");
               } 



        if(newValue.equals("")|| m.hitEnd()){

            setStyle("fx-control-inner-background: transparent;");

        }
      }  
  });
```

}

De esta forma va progresivamente comprobando si coincide lo introducido(cada nuevo String) con el patron

saludos